# Django: conditional expression

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Agreement(models.Model):
    ...
    organization = models.ForeignKey("Organization")

class Signed_Agreement(models.Model):
    agreement = models.ForeignKey("Agreement")
    member = models.ForeignKey("Member")
```

What I'm trying to do is get a list of all the agreements for a particular organization (self.organization) and annotate each agreement with information about whether or not it has been signed by a particular member (self.member).

If the Agreement has been signed, then there exists an instance of Signed_Agreement for the particular agreement and member.

How do I write a query for this?

Here's my effort so far:

```
from django.db.models import When, F, Q, Value

def get_queryset(self):

    agreements = _agreement_model.Agreement.objects.filter(
        organization=self.organization
    ).annotate(
        signed=When(Q(signed_agreement__member=self.member), then=Value(True))
    ).order_by(
        'name'
    )

    return agreements
```

This is not producing the correct results.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you want to be using a [`Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) here.

```
def get_queryset(self):

    agreements = _agreement_model.Agreement.objects.filter(
        organization=self.organization
    ).annotate(
        signed=Case(When(signed_agreement__member=F('member')),
                    then=Value(True),
                    default=Value(False),
                    output_field=BooleanField()
    ).order_by(
        'name'
    )

    return agreements
```

**UPDATE**

Per comments it appears that in later versions of Django that the `then` must be passed in the `When`

```
def get_queryset(self):

    agreements = _agreement_model.Agreement.objects.filter(
        organization=self.organization
    ).annotate(
        signed=Case(When(signed_agreement__member=F('member'), 
                         then=Value(True)
                    ),
                    default=Value(False),
                    output_field=BooleanField()
    ).order_by(
        'name'
    )

    return agreements
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this gets me very close to what I want. I am getting this error: 
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field

Do you know what this means?

Comment: Looks like you have to tell the `Case` what type of field it is, I have edited the answer to do so

Comment: As mentioned in dm295's answer, `then=Value(True)` needs to be passed in with `When()` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer didn't work for me with `Django 1.11.6`. I had to put [`then` inside `When`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when) to make it work.

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, F, BooleanField


def get_queryset(self):
    agreements = _agreement_model.Agreement.objects.filter(
        organization=self.organization
    ).annotate(
        signed=Case(
            When(
                signed_agreement__member=F('member'),
                then=True
            ),
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField()
        )
    ).order_by(
        'name'
    )
```